# how do i set a the chrome clear history function for all time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that clears all history ever time a website is loaded or reloaded.

below is how to remove data from a week back but how do i do it for all time?

```
var millisecondsPerWeek = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
      var oneWeekAgo = (new Date()).getTime() - millisecondsPerWeek;
      chrome.browsingData.remove({
        "since": oneWeekAgo
      }, {
        "appcache": true,
        "cache": true,
        "cacheStorage": true,
        "cookies": true,
        "downloads": true,
        "fileSystems": true,
        "formData": true,
        "history": true,
        "indexedDB": true,
        "localStorage": true,
        "pluginData": true,
        "passwords": true,
        "serviceWorkers": true,
        "webSQL": true
      }, callback);
```

Also, I'm not exactly sure about how to implement the when a website is loaded or reloaded part... This is all I've got

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete')
```

Comment: As you can see in the documentation specifying `since: 0` will clear the entire history.

Comment: As for the site part, chrome.history.onVisited + chrome.history.deleteUrl may be a better fit.